# Do I need to log into the remote desktop environment first before connecting to it by xpra or VNC?

Tags: ssh, vnc, xpra

I connect to a remote Lubuntu PC by:

```
xpra shadow ssh:t@olive:0
```

When I log out of the remote Lubuntu, the connection of [xpra](https://xpra.org/) is lost.

When I try to connect to a remote Lubuntu which I haven't logged in, I have never succeeded in connecting.

Do I need to log into the remote destktop first before I can connect to it by xpra? Why?

Same questions for vnc?

If I can't physically go to the remote to log in, is there a way to remotely connect to it by xpra? By [VNC](http://ipinfo.info/html/vnc_remote_control.php)?

Why can I log into the remote machine by [ssh](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol/), without logging into it beforehand?

Comment: 1 of 2 -- In my experience, "sometimes". One of my labs is a number of RHEL7 VM servers, with a small number of RHEL5 physical workstations. Red Hat Identity Management (FreeIPA, upstream) is the directory. Users home dirss are on an NFS server, mounted at login time. `mkhomedir` option is used so when firstlogin to a new system occurs, if home does not exist the login routine creates it. On RHEL5, when logging in to Gnome via GDM, the system looks for req'd .gnome and other X configs. Inmost cases it creates them if missing. However, if home folder doesn't exist, it fails with strange errors.

Comment: 2 of 2 -- The order of operations for the login routines and processes is important. Unfortunately I don't know a lot about these. My experience is from trial and error. "When you login the very first time via GDM, it fails. When you login the first time at a terminal, /home/$user is created. Then, logging in via GDM works fine."
Hopefully that helps you at least make progress down the path.
I've had similar (but different) results when running automation against newly built systems (Ansible using SSH), if the proper considerations are not addressed (unknown SSH identity key, etc.)